# How do scrape these page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How we scrape `website link` from this page I am trying to scrape but I don't understand logic how we scrape the website link the page of the link as example is [https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractors/capital-remodeling-pfvwus-pf~663981496](https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractors/capital-remodeling-pfvwus-pf%7E663981496)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd

# location of chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/chromedriver/94/chromedriver.exe")

# opening website
driver.get("https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractor")

# waiting for the DIVs to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="hz-pro-search-result__right-info"]')))

# getting all the relevant DIVs
info_divs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  '//div[@class="hz-pro-search-result__right-info"]')

house_details = {
    "address": [],
    "phone": []
}

for row in info_divs:
    try:
        address = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "hz-pro-search-result__right-info__full-address")
        phone = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "hz-pro-search-result__right-info__contact-info")
        phone.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        house_details['address'].append(address.text)
        house_details['phone'].append(phone.text)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"something went wrong. {ex}")
        
# saving to dataframe
house_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(house_details)
# exporting to .csv
house_df.to_csv('house_details.csv', index=False)

print(house_df)
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you not understand? What is the question here?

Comment: if you go to these page https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractors/capital-remodeling-pfvwus-pf~663981496 there is website link on right side I am trying to scrape it

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the "Website" link appearing on the right side of the [link you provided](https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractors/capital-remodeling-pfvwus-pf%7E663981496)  you can use this XPath:

```
//div[@data-section="Right Rail"]//a[@data-component="Pro Website Link"]
```

With Selenium commands it can be something like this:

```py
link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-section="Right Rail"]//a[@data-component="Pro Website Link"]')))
link_value = link.get_attribute('href')
print(link_value)
```

To use the above expected conditions you will need to import

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And initialize the `wait` object

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Comment: thanks but these code will provide only link of website  But also get phone and address

Comment: No, this will give you only the link.